# How to call the main function in C file by JNI in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing an application where I have to use the `Live555` on Android 4.4.2 .

`Live555` is a C source code for `Media Streaming` , and I have to call it by `JNI`.

I have build the .so for `Live555` like the following picture:

[image]

I want to call the C source code by JNI

**`The question 1`**

**Which libraries should I load by using `System.loadLibrary` like the following code in `JAVA` ?**

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("What libraries name should I load ?");
    }
```

**`The question 2`**

How to call the **`main`** function in **`java`** by using **`public native String main;`**
(**main function is in `jni/mediaServer/live555MediaServer.cpp`**)

The C source code of **`live555MediaServer.cpp`** is like the following:

```
#include <BasicUsageEnvironment.hh>
#include "DynamicRTSPServer.hh"
#include "version.hh"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
  TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
  UsageEnvironment* env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

  UserAuthenticationDatabase* authDB = NULL;
#ifdef ACCESS_CONTROL
  // To implement client access control to the RTSP server, do the following:
  authDB = new UserAuthenticationDatabase;
  authDB->addUserRecord("username1", "password1"); // replace these with real strings
  // Repeat the above with each <username>, <password> that you wish to allow
  // access to the server.
#endif

  // Create the RTSP server.  Try first with the default port number (554),
  // and then with the alternative port number (8554):
  RTSPServer* rtspServer;
  portNumBits rtspServerPortNum = 554;
  rtspServer = DynamicRTSPServer::createNew(*env, rtspServerPortNum, authDB);
  if (rtspServer == NULL) {
    rtspServerPortNum = 8554;
    rtspServer = DynamicRTSPServer::createNew(*env, rtspServerPortNum, authDB);
  }
  if (rtspServer == NULL) {
    *env << "Failed to create RTSP server: " << env->getResultMsg() << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  *env << "LIVE555 Media Server\n";
  *env << "\tversion " << MEDIA_SERVER_VERSION_STRING
       << " (LIVE555 Streaming Media library version "
       << LIVEMEDIA_LIBRARY_VERSION_STRING << ").\n";

  char* urlPrefix = rtspServer->rtspURLPrefix();
  *env << "Play streams from this server using the URL\n\t"
       << urlPrefix << "<filename>\nwhere <filename> is a file present in the current directory.\n";
  *env << "Each file's type is inferred from its name suffix:\n";
  *env << "\t\".264\" => a H.264 Video Elementary Stream file\n";
  *env << "\t\".aac\" => an AAC Audio (ADTS format) file\n";
  *env << "\t\".ac3\" => an AC-3 Audio file\n";
  *env << "\t\".amr\" => an AMR Audio file\n";
  *env << "\t\".dv\" => a DV Video file\n";
  *env << "\t\".m4e\" => a MPEG-4 Video Elementary Stream file\n";
  *env << "\t\".mkv\" => a Matroska audio+video+(optional)subtitles file\n";
  *env << "\t\".mp3\" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Audio file\n";
  *env << "\t\".mpg\" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream (audio+video) file\n";
  *env << "\t\".ts\" => a MPEG Transport Stream file\n";
  *env << "\t\t(a \".tsx\" index file - if present - provides server 'trick play' support)\n";
  *env << "\t\".vob\" => a VOB (MPEG-2 video with AC-3 audio) file\n";
  *env << "\t\".wav\" => a WAV Audio file\n";
  *env << "\t\".webm\" => a WebM audio(Vorbis)+video(VP8) file\n";
  *env << "See http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/ for additional documentation.\n";

  // Also, attempt to create a HTTP server for RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling.
  // Try first with the default HTTP port (80), and then with the alternative HTTP
  // port numbers (8000 and 8080).

  if (rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(80) || rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(8000) || rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(8080)) {
    *env << "(We use port " << rtspServer->httpServerPortNum() << " for optional RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling, or for HTTP live streaming (for indexed Transport Stream files only).)\n";
  } else {
    *env << "(RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling is not available.)\n";
  }

  env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(); // does not return

  return 0; // only to prevent compiler warning
}
```

**-------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------**

```
jni/live555.cpp:33:11: error: 'argc' was not declared in this scope
jni/live555.cpp:33:17: error: 'argv' was not declared in this scope
jni/live555.cpp:33:21: error: 'main' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 4):

```
static {
        // order matters when you have more ".so" files.
        System.loadLibrary("live555");
    }
```

Now to call the main function with parameters. create a JNI method that takes an array of strings, and simply call that method. In the JNI convert the array of strings to array of C strings, and you are done.

```
JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL Java_full_package_name_classname_functionname(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, Jobject stringArray){
    // your argc
    int size = env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);
    char **argv = new char*[size];
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        jstring string = env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArrays, i);
        const char* cString = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);
        argv[i] = strdup(cString);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, myarray);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(string);
    }
    // you will need to modify main so it does properly cleanup
    main(argc, argv);
    // clean up
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(argv[i]);
    delete [] argv;
}
```

You should try some hello world apps to get Java<--->c++ code working on android and the rest should be fairly obvious. Check the android samples. They have good JNI samples.

Comment: I have reference the sample of `Hello-JNI`. It load the libraries by using `System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");` , but I can not find which libraries name hello-jni...

Comment: when you do `ndk-build` to build the c++ code it generates an ".so" file like "libNAME.so" whatever "NAME" is you pass into System.loadLibrary("NAME");

Comment: Thanks for you , but what you mean wrong about `stdc++.a` ? I reference the following link http://blog.csdn.net/sunwutian0325/article/details/8582524. And it seems also has stdc++.a. Does it something wrong ?

Comment: Never mind it's right. I was looking at the wrong thing

Comment: It seems can not use `main(argc, argv);` to call main in `cpp`. It show the error like the content I edit.

Comment: Do you have other method?

Comment: Those errors you have with "not declared ..." are fairly straight forward. Usually there is no prototype for main. But in your case you will need declare a prototype. instead of `argc` it should be `size` in my example. I don't know why argv is undeclared, you should double check your code for typos, and make sure argv is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1-  any library you plan on calling directly from Java.  Anything you call by C will be dealt with by the C linker.

Question 2-  you shouldn't call main directly.  You can only call functions with the correct naming convention.  You need to make a Java object with a function defined as native.  Then in the C code you need a matching  JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL Java_full_package_name_classname_functionname(JNIEnv *, jobject, params);

Then just call the java native functions.

Comment: **For Question 1 :** But I don't know where is the libraries can I call ?

**For Question 2 :** Thansk , I know I have to use `native`. But if the C source code is like the content I have edit , what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Appending @over_optimistic response

If someone needs a C equivalent

---

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_nativ_com_nativejnitest_MainActivity_functionname(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray stringArray){

jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, stringArray);


char **argv = (char **)malloc(size);

for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) 
{
    jstring javaString = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, i);
    const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaString, 0);

    argv[i] = strdup(nativeString);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString, nativeString);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, javaString);
}

// Sample Response
char *msgOut;
asprintf(&msgOut, "Response is %d ", size);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, msgOut);
```

};

---

Done.